# Put UITabBar on top of the screen within UITabBarController - Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I subclassed UITabBarController to allow for a custom UITabBar positioned at the top of the screen.

The issue is that when I set the frame for the UITabBar to the top, it moves and works properly, but there seems to be an overlay that remains at the bottom of the screen in the place where is was the UITabbar also the view is under the uitabbar.

```
public class TopTabBarController : UITabBarController
{
        public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

            var tabFrame = this.TabBar.Frame;
            tabFrame.Y = 64;

            this.TabBar.Frame = tabFrame;
        }
}
```

[See Image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4297.png)

Comment: Are you aware that this is against apple design guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

I have created the new tab bar project for iPhone and added the code you have provided in the project I have created. And tested the application it works as expected its not keeping space at the bottom.

I think you need to check the frame of view or the scroll view you have used in your application. Check the bottom constraints for the view it should be zero from bottom.

[image: Tabbar at top screenshot]